# How to run Flet app without Flutter for mobile

Tags: python, flutter, mobile, flet

I discovered that Flet app runs on desktop (linux) without the needs of flutter. I want to know if there is anyway to package or run Flet app without Flutter on Android or iOS.

```
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.add(ft.Text("Hello World!") 

ft.app(target=main)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run flet app without flutter

To Build flet to android
Just type

`flet build apk`